# MDX Multi Select Divide by CurrentMember.Properties

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

Error: "The MDX function CURRENTMEMBER failed because the coordinate for the 'YYYYMM' attribute contains a set."

I have a calculation that works when only a single months data is returned. My Calendar dimension contains a single record per year month (Key: YYYYMM) and includes a property of "Man Hours".

As I understand it this is due to the implementation or lack there of, of multi select support.

This is T-SQL that would returen the expected value.

```
SELECT CostPerManHour = SUM(MonthCost) / SUM(ManHours)
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        MonthCost = SUM(C.Cost), 
        Cal.ManHours 
    FROM dbo.Costs C
    JOIN dbo.Calendar Cal ON C.YYYYMM = Cal.YYYYMM
    WHERE Cal.YYYYMM BETWEEN 201503 AND 201705
      AND C.OtherThing = 'Thing1'
    GROUP BY Cal.YYYYMM, Cal.ManHours 
    ) Q
;
```

MDX:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Cost Per Man Hour],... ON 0
FROM Metrics
WHERE { 
    { [Calendar].[YYYYMM].&[201503] : [Calendar].[YYYYMM].&[201705] }
  * { [Other Thing].[Other Thing].&[Thing1] }
};
```

Calculation

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Cost Per Man Hour] 
 AS DIVIDE([Measures].[Cost], [CALENDAR].[YYYYMM].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES ("Man Hours")), 
VISIBLE = 1,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Costs';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Cost Per Man Hour] 
 AS 
 DIVIDE(
    [Measures].[Cost],
    SUM(
        existing [Calendar].[YYYYMM].[YYYYMM].Members,
        [CALENDAR].[YYYYMM].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES ("Man Hours")
    )
 ), 
VISIBLE = 1,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Costs';
```

Comment: Thats it, thank you. The only change I needed to make was to use StrToValue on the property.

Comment: Looks like I prematurely accepted this.
The calculation is returning CostPerManHour = SUM(MonthCost / ManHours) instead of CostPerManHour = SUM(MonthCost) / SUM(ManHours).

Comment: Try to split sum() into a separate calculation. It shouldn't divide per month.

Comment: Bingo, you were correct. I had some extra months included that didn’t have data. That was what was messing up the calc. My ignorance lead to me incorrectly interpreting the output. Thank you again for your help.

I dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude month Man Hours when that months [Measures].[Cost] is null?

Comment: Sure: IIF([Measures].[Cost],StrToValue([CALENDAR].[YYYYMM].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("Man Hours")),NULL)

Comment: Thank you again.
I had tried IIF([Measures].[Cost] IS NULL,StrToValue([CALENDAR].[YYYYMM].CURRENT‌​MEMBER.PROPERTIES("M‌​an Hours")),NULL), but that didn't work. I just assumed it had to do with the way it was being evailuated. Do you know why IIF accepts [Measures].[Cost] as a logical expression? Is it just following old school numeric boolean rules, anything not null or 0 is true?

Comment: Yeah, if it contains a value IIF returns true. There is no "is null" in MDX, you have to use IsEmpty([Measures].[Cost]) instead.